# OpenGL ES clarifying question regarding FBOs -- sorry can't find this info anywhere else?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

If I instantiate an FBO without binding a rendering buffer or a texture to it, what happens when I draw to it, nothing?

Do I need to associate a rendering target (renderbuffer or texture) to have an FBO do anything? What I'm trying to do is precache some buffers and then merge them later, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

Ideally I'd like to do something like

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, fbo1);
// Draw some stuff to fbo1
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, fbo2);
// Draw some stuff to fbo2
// ...
// ...
// glRenderFbo(fbo1); -- Not a func
// Set blending, etc. etc.
// glRenderFbo(fbo2); -- Not a func
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is nothing.  I'd like you to read my response to your other question.

[How to merge two FBOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519567/how-to-merge-two-fbos/2520993#2520993)